# How to create form like this in one page (method include how we implement it)

Tags: php

Purchase Request Form.

> [image: Purchase Request Form]

We implement above form using two tables (One table to store create basic form details and second one to store add item details)

**First form to create basic form details**

> [image: Create Basic Details]

**Second Form to add item details.**

> [image: Add Item details]

But our project supervisor reject that method, he want's form create and add item in one page. Please help us to find solution.

Comment: The `Table` you are referring to is the HTML Table for layout, or is it the db ? Also, that order form looks very similar to the ones used in my place(South India). With round seal, etc. Looks very familiar. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My basic example may suitable for your requirement http://jsfiddle.net/8tAK7/. 
Then on your form handler you can simply retrieve `$_POST['items']` to get items array values (based on my example above).

Then on your handler (i assume it PHP), you can split the string based on delimiter you set on the value:

```
$items = $_POST['items'];

foreach($items as $item){
    $values = explode(";", $item);

    $item_desc = $values[0];
    $item_price = $values[1];
    $item_qty = $values[2];

    // TODO: insert to DB
}
```

Comment: See here http://jsfiddle.net/8tAK7/, this might not the best approach but can be simplest solution. You need to simply explode the value you get on your post handler to save them on your DB. I have also edited my answer hope it helps :)

Comment: Thanks very much friend....really great work..

Could you give more help friend,my still beginning to jquery.

Comment: How to create first column[http://i.stack.imgur.com/GqDYr.png]
1,2,3 according to rows add

Comment: Sorry for late reply, do you mean create it in the view or database? My example is only the basic idea, you still need to improve it until meets your requirements. You may be more specific so we can get what you actually want to accomplish.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/8tAK7/ ,This code works in in this site..so we put this code our pc & write a script & run it..but It's not work in wampserver..wht's the problem ???can not undestand..plzz help us fix this error...this is the code we put in wampsever: http://jsfiddle.net/dontspeak/8q6Dp/

Comment: Make sure that your jquery-1.8.2.js library is on the right path when you load it. By looking at your code it should be on the same relative path with your html file. It will be easier if you can show me your live site so that I can find out if there's any problem with it. You can also find the error by looking in Console of Inspect Element (you can use Chrome/Firebug).

Comment: The problem was caused by jquery library that was not loaded. Please see here https://dl.dropbox.com/u/78566197/test.html. If you need to learn about jquery here the link you can start with http://api.jquery.com/.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this by creating a empty row and set the session with that row id on the load of page and than insert.. and check after every some minute that the  session id is present if not than delete or if inserted than set the status to 1 (0 when creating the row)